# How to execute some code when a file is modified using python?

Tags: python, file, function, execute

I want to execute one function each time a file gets written with new data (gets modified) and I'm using Python.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to monitor for changes in the file system using Python, see [this article](http://www.stepthreeprofit.com/2008/06/cross-platform-monitoring-of-filesystem.html) for pointers to libraries which can help you achieve this on different platforms.

Short summary of available libraries for different platforms:

- Windows: [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)
- OS X: [pyKQueue](http://people.freebsd.org/~dwhite/PyKQueue/)
- Linux: [Gamin](http://www.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/python.html)

Remember that your program needs to be running to handle file system events.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that it's not necessarily your Python program that's modifying the file. I don't know if there's an OS-independent method. On Linux you can use [pyinotify](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify).